# Receive certain type of message only in android

Tags: android, sms, messaging, prefix

I would like to know how to set prefix (if that's what it is called) to a SMS application I'm creating to receive certain type of messages. example:

I want my application to receive only SMS that has a `++` (2 plus sign)  at the beginning of the message body. and normal messages without the ++ will go to the built in messaging application.

a) Is it possible?

b) If yes, than how and where do I set it?

c) I would like more tutorials on SMS application.
 pls guide me through

Comment: If I recall correctly and you listen for SMS (intents?) you will get all SMS messages. From there you can filter for the '++'.

Comment: yes. i have set the android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED and android:priority ="99999". but where must i put this ++?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few examples of receiving SMS on an android app. [Here's](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html) a simple one.

It's quite easy to recognize only your messages. I don't know if you can delete SMS messages without letting the user see them. Seems like a very big security whole, and I wouldn't be surprised if this was prohibited on a non-rooted phone.

Comment: yes. it doesn't matter if the user needs to see the message and than deleting it. but i need to set the ++ sign somewhere. but im unsure of it.. must i place the ++ sign at androidmanifest file or the java class?

Comment: Put it in your Java class. Look for it in the SMS text in Java code.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that.

> > Read incoming messages.
> >     Check message body for ++ sign
> >     save it to your application database if it has ++ sign in the beginning and delete the message